# 2D array not printing the last element during comparison

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to replace rows from an original 2d array to a updated 2d array. Problem is it won't store the last element during the replacement.

Here's my code:

```
String[][] updatedArray = {{"red","a","b","c"},{"yellow","a","b","c"}, {"purple","a","b","c"}};

    String[][] originalArray = {{"red","aa","bb","cc"},{"yellow","ww","vv","zz"}, {"green","yy","uu","pp"}, {"purple","nn","mm","bb","hello"}};

    for (int i = 0; i < updatedArray.length;i++ ) {
        for (int j = 0; j < updatedArray[i].length; j++){
            for(int x = 0; x < originalArray.length;x++){
                for(int z = 0; z < originalArray[x].length;z++){
                if(originalArray[x][0].equals(updatedArray[i][0])) {
                    updatedArray[i][j] = originalArray[x][j];
                    System.out.println("There's a match!!");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("No match!");
                }
            }
            }
        }   
    }

    System.out.println("originalArray:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(originalArray));
    System.out.println("updatedArray:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(updatedArray));
```

For example, initially updatedArray in last row "purple" has `{"purple","a","b","c"}`. When it does the replacement using values from originalArray, the code above only outputs:

> ... [purple, nn, mm, bb]

which is wrong because it doesn't add the last element "hello". It should output:

> ... [purple, nn, mm, bb, hello]

I am aware the problem is in this line:

> updatedArray[i][j] = originalArray[x][j];

Problem is no matter what I try to change originalArray[x][j] to originalArray[x][**z**] ... its screws up everything.

Any ideas on this? Still trying to get the jist of 2D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a match, instead of trying to set each element in the updatedArray to the corresponding element in the original array you can just set the entire array to the original array.

```
String[][] updatedArray = {{"red","a","b","c"},{"yellow","a","b","c"}, {"purple","a","b","c"}};

String[][] originalArray = {{"red","aa","bb","cc"},{"yellow","ww","vv","zz"}, {"green","yy","uu","pp"}, {"purple","nn","mm","bb","hello"}};

for (int i = 0; i < updatedArray.length;i++ ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < originalArray.length; j++){
        if(originalArray[j][0].equals(updatedArray[i][0])) {
            updatedArray[i] = originalArray[j];
            System.out.println("There's a match!!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No match!");
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you chose to iterate over the dimensions of updatedArray which are different than the dimensions of originalArray.

Let just look at the case i=2 which is the 'row' for purple:

```
for (int j = 0; j < updatedArray[i].length; j++){ 

updatedArray[i=2].length = 4
```

in updated:

```
index =   0      , 1 , 2 , 3
        {"purple","a","b","c"}
```

in original:

```
index =   0      , 1 ,  2 ,  3  , 4
        {"purple","nn","mm","bb","hello"}
```

Therefore since j will always be < 4 it can never be used to index originalArray[x][4] = "hello"

**DANGER**: this code also doesn't handle the fact that you would need to extend the purple array for updatedArray. Java may do some magic to handle this for you but I wouldn't trust it to work that way.

Suggestion:
- compare the lengths of each row and allocate extra memory where necessary before copying data from originalArray to updatedArray
- if possible just copy the whole row between original and updated.